# XslCompiledTransform fails on xsl:import

Tags: c#, .net, uri, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have few XSLT files, index stylesheet imports layout using xsl:import. VS says that XSLT is valid, but Load operation raises xslt compilation exception, it says cannot import my layout file. It tries ti find it in c:\windows\system32 instead of my project dir.

Index.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:h ="urn:helper"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:import href="..\Shared\Layout.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/content" mode="content">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and Layout.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/xml" mode="content" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Next I'm trying to apply transformation on my XML:

```
string viewPath = "~/Views/Home/Index.xsl";
var stylesheet = HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.GetFile(viewPath);
var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (var stream = stylesheet.Open())
using (var tmpl = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    xsl.Load(tmpl, null, new XmlUrlResolver());
}
```

Comment: A backslash is not a valid path separator in a URI. Try a forwards slash. I doubt it will make a difference - Microsoft software tends to forgive this error - but it will eliminate one possible cause, and make your code more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that ASP.NET? Then use

```
  xsl.Load(MapPath(viewPath), null, new XmlUrlResolver());
```